# How to allow only getter/setter to get/set variable value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this example, a user can still access and set the variable using:

```
obj = C()
obj._x=10
varA  = obj._x
```

Even if we use `__x` instead of `_x` in below code, `x` still doesn't become private. So the only purpose of `_x` is to let the programmers know that it is not meant to be set directly via `obj._x`?

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x
```

Comment: No.  Python is a language for "consenting adults"; that is, we may indicate that a variable is private via a leading underscore, but we  don't enforce privacy like C++/C#/Java.  The double leading underscore has a specific purpose: mimicking the access modifiers in other languages is not that purpose.

Comment: Even a leading double underscore won't prevent modification, it will just make it "harder" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name

Comment: Python doesn't have private. Not even double-underscore name-mangling. That isn't what double-underscore name-mangling is for. Your example using property is not what you should be doing.

Comment: Ok so in this example, the purpose of property is to ensure that when value is assigned or fetched using obj.x, then, it calls the appropriate getter/setter which will apply logic if any and then get/set the value from/to _x respectively

Comment: @variable And in that case, you should (probably) be assigning to the property *everywhere*, even in `__init__`, instead of bypassing and assigning directly to `_x`.

Comment: @variable if your getter and setters don't apply any logic then *don't use a property* that defeats the entire point! This example should just have an `__init__` that assigns to `self.x`. then later if you decide you want to manage how `self.x` is accessed, **then you add the property**. It's encapsulation without boilerplate. That's *the beauty of it*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, it is a convention to use `_var_name` in order to indicate that something is private, but it does not enforce it like in languages as C++, C#, Java, etc.

A double underscore prefix causes the Python interpreter to rewrite the attribute name in order to avoid naming conflicts in subclasses.

This is also called name mangling—the interpreter changes the name of the variable in a way that makes it harder to create collisions when the class is extended later.

Consider the following example

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 11
        self._bar = 23
        self.__baz = 23
```

Now, let's run the following code:

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> dir(t)
['_Test__baz', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__',
 '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__',
 '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__',
 '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__', '_bar', 'foo']
```

`dir(t)` gives us a list with the object’s attributes. When you search for `__baz` in that list you’ll see that there is no variable with that name. If you look closely you’ll see there’s an attribute called `_Test__baz` on this object. This is the name mangling that the Python interpreter applies.

Comment: Ok so even removing the single underscore doesnt make any difference technically

Comment: @variable, it doesn't. As user `snakecharmerb` has told you. This is an agreed convention, so you can simply break the rules, but Pythonistas has agreed to respect it.

Comment: @variable Again, **Python does not have private variables**. [It says that right in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables). If you are looking for that, use another language

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thank you so much to provide links to the documentation.

Comment: The purpose of property is to ensure that when value is assigned or fetched using obj.x, then, it calls the appropriate getter/setter which will apply logic if any and then get/set the value from/to _x respectively ?

Comment: @variable, that is the definition of a getter and a setter in some programming languages like C++, C# or Java. In Python, `property` is decorator that helps you to achieve the same result. However, adding an `_` does not guarantee you that the variable won't be accessed, so considering you are following the conventions, the property will allow you access/set this property.

Comment: Makes sense thanks